# Optimize database connection with hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-connection

I ma working on a hibernate applciation and I use `hibernate.c3po` configuration in order to adjust the number of possible connections. My problem is that some users have complained that the Database Connection crashed after some minutes of use. In the `cfg` file I use additionally the following lines:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
```

In the transactions I use always the `currentSession`:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = HibernateUtil.getTransaction(session);

    try 
        {
            tx.begin();
            session.update(u);
            tx.commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What would be an appropriate improvement/optimization in order to make the database connnection reliable? 
Should I use the `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` property as well? How would be its impact in this case?

Would it be better if I use `openSession` instead of `getCurrentSession`? I had the impression though that `session` is not related to `connection`. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "DB Connection Crashed"? Do you have any log statements for that?

Comment: I have not currently log statements, because the error has only been mentioned by users.

Comment: Not much that others can help without more information